# WebView - YouTube cookie data - windows 8 store app

Tags: c#-4.0, youtube-api, windows-store-apps, youtube-javascript-api, youtube.net-api

I'm trying to get a WebView control in a Windows 8 Store App to somehow pick up that a user has been logged on so that I could get the "Watch Later" button to work. I have been able to authenticate a user using the WebAuthenticationBroker and also getting the Access Token. I can also send and get requests using the Access Token. I just need to be able to get my WebView control to know that the user has been logged in so that the YouTube HTML5 player can use the features on the player itself (eg Watch later - right now it says I need to sign in).

Comment: The user will need to be authenticated again using the Google sign-in page in the WebView. The traditional YouTube page does not use OAUTH.

Comment: Yes I agree. The thing is that I cannot authenticate the user in the WebView using the javascript way recommended by YouTube. It tries to inject javascript into the Windows 8 App and then just gives an error telling me that it cannot be done. Is there any other way to build up a cookie and then make the WebView read that in so that the YouTube player can recognize the user?

Comment: Guess nobody has any answer for me...dammit :(